# Ubuntu 18.04 gtk3 css theme

Tags: gnome, themes

I have adapted the arc theme to match ubuntu 18.04.

One thing that I can not find in the gtk3.css file in my theme is why there is a line between the panel and a maximized window.

[image]

I don't know what to change in the theme to get rid of the line.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: could it be a shadow setting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was indeed drop shadow with maximized windows.

```css
.maximized separator:first-child + headerbar,
.tiled separator:first-child + headerbar, .maximized separator:first-child + headerbar:backdrop,
.tiled separator:first-child + headerbar:backdrop, .maximized headerbar:first-child,
.tiled headerbar:first-child, .maximized headerbar:first-child:backdrop,
.tiled headerbar:first-child:backdrop {
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;  }
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! There is no need to create a new account to answer your question. You can always answer your own question and mark it as solved with one account.